# Find the wrong way word

Tags: javascript

I have a challenge where I need to create a function that takes an array. The array is filled with strings that are all the same except for one, which is spelled backwards. I need to identify the string and return its index position.

The code I tried is the following

```
const petList = ['god','dog', 'dog', 'dog']

function findWrongWayWord(pets) {

  const petOne = pets[0];
    if (pets.length<3) {
    return 0;
  }

  for (let i = 1; i < pets.length; i++) {
    if (pets[i] !== petOne) {
      return pets.indexOf(pets[i]);
    }
  }
}

findWrongWayWord(petList)
```

And sort of works, but only that when the word that's backwards is at the start of the array, it does not return the right index.

Comment: Is there only one bad word, or multiple? I'm assuming one

Comment: There is only one bad word, Martijn.

Comment: Compare the first two elements. If they're the same, then look for another element that's different, it's the bad word. If they're not the same, then whichever one is different from the third element is the bad word.

Comment: @Barmar That would be a more neat solution as OPs version, but that has the same problem: Only works at the start. If you have 3+ values it wont work

Comment: @Martijn I see Barmar's solution as working for any length of array that has at least three elements. If the first two elements are the same, then you know what the "correct" word is, and you can find the different one. If they're different, then you know one of them is "correct" and one is the "bad" one; you break the tie by looking at the third element.

Answer (score 4):

if all the items in an array are same except the one, then all you need is a non repeated distinct unique value in array.

```
petList.filter(num => petList.indexOf(num) === petList.lastIndexOf(num))
```

We search for the index for each value from the start and from the last value. If those are the same index, only one exists.

Comment: Mine explains better, but this is very clever :) Have my +1

Comment: I've added an explanation :)

Comment: Lol thanks mate :)

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in a comment, the most efficient way starts by comparing the first two elements.

If the first two are the same, the outlier is the next element that's different from the first element.

If the first two are different, one of them is the outlier. Whichever is different from the third element is the outlier.

```js
function findWrongWayWord(pets) {
  if (pets.length < 3) {
    return 0;
  }

  const [petOne, petTwo, petThree] = pets;

  if (petOne == petTwo) {
    // First two are the same, find something different
    return pets.findIndex(p => p != petOne);
  } else {
    // First two are different, return whichever is different from third pet
    return petOne == petThree ? 1 : 0;
  }    
}

console.log(findWrongWayWord(['god', 'dog', 'dog', 'dog']));
console.log(findWrongWayWord(['dog', 'god', 'dog', 'dog']));
console.log(findWrongWayWord(['dog', 'dog', 'god', 'dog']));
console.log(findWrongWayWord(['dog', 'dog', 'dog', 'god']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: [The answer by Syed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77353579/2519416) is a lot more elegant, I'll leave this as an alternative solution to solve these kinds of challanges

---

The reason it only works for the first one, is because you only check it against the first one (`const petOne = pets[0]`). You could loop through everything, but there is a simpler logic:

However long your array is, when you find the match (even though we dont know that yet), you only need two other values. You need 3 values to determine the odd one out.

The rules to make this work:

- If less than 3 items: return false (no way to know which is reversed)
- Now we loop through the items:

  - Add value to array, increase value by one
  - When we have two different words stored, and at least 3 values: find the singular one

```js
function findWrongWayWord(pets) {
    if (pets.length < 3) {
        return -1; // or false, but JS uses -1 sometimes too
    }
  
    let stored= {};
    for (let i = 1; i < pets.length; i++) {
        stored[pets[i]] = 1 + (stored[pets[i]] || 0);

        if (i >= 3) {
            if (stored.length === 2) {
                const oddOneOut = stored[0].length === 1 ? stored[0] : stored[1];
                return pets.indexOf(oddOneOut);
            }
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Please note: untested code

Comment: Hiya! Thanks a lot for the time you took to reply. In the end I used a Map object to store the pet count. Then I used Array.from() and find() to find the less common value comming from the map object using .get() and Math.min()